# Alerta de compilação do Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Fala galera eu estou desenvolvendo um projeto em Windows Forms, e recentemente fiz um upgrade do Visual Studio 2010 para o 2015, porem quando eu fiz a instalação do VS 2015 percebi que nao havia o report View entao fiz a instalação dele para colocar no meu projeto como forma de relatorio.

Em fim quando finalizei meu projeto e fui exportar para um .Exe, vi que meu VS2015 apresentou um alerta alegando 2 mensagem alguem poderia me ajudar a resolver.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não são erros, são avisos.

Comment: certo, e como eu reparo esses avisos para que nao ocorra ?

Answer (score 1):

Galera descobri o motivo do erro, foi uma referencia que adicionou no meu projeto do ReportViewer.